# How do you point Intellij idea (14.1) at a maven pom that is not called pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have multiple pom.xml files in my directory based on the packaging I choose -- pom.xml, pom-webapp.xml, etc. (For various reasons, it is easier to maintain separate files than separate targets).
However, when I try to import "as maven" into an intellij module, I can't select pom-webapp.xml, only pom.xml.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: shift-f6 rename -> pom.xml, add it as maven project, then try to rename it back ?